# OpenMP treat all static variables as threadprivate by default

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a C function that I need to run on multiple inputs in parallel.

I am trying to use OpenMP to do so, the issue is, that the function I am using is using some internal static variables for its own internal calculations.

When trying to run multiple instances of this function in parallel, the program crashes due to the fact that multiple threads are accessing the same memory region.

This can be solved by defining each and every static variable as "threadprivate", but since I have many internal variables, this is a bit overkill.

Is there any way to make OpenMP treat all variables as "threadprivate" by default?

Comment: I don't think it would be a good idea to allow one to force a compiler to treat `static` variables as `threadprivate` by some outer mechanism (such as a compiler flag). That would then confuse a reader of such code.

Comment: It doesn't matter to me ATM since I am only using OpenMP on my testing code just to make it run faster, and not as part of the production code.

Comment: Why is this question tagged C and C++? What do you actually use?

Comment: @Zulan I use C++ to run my tests (using Catch2 testing framework), while the function I am testing is written in C (which is the reason all private internal members are global).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such possibility.

No you could maybe attempt some adventurous `#define static`, but I would strongly advise against that.

The thing is. A function using `static` isn't suddenly thread-safe if you replace all of them with thread-locals. Consider:

```
int unique_number() {
    static i = 0;
    return i++; // surely this is unique!
}
```

It gets worse if you have functions capturing state across invocations such as the infamous `strtok`:

```
my_threadlocal_strtok(str, ...);
#pragma omp parallel for
for () {
    my_threadlocal_strtok(NULL, ...); //
}
```

You have to consider the "lifecycle" of this static - or now threadlocal - state.

Defining a bunch of `threadlocal` variables that used to be `static` makes it much harder to reason about parallel code and is likely going to introduce subtle bugs. The same goes for global variables, by the way, which also make parallelization much harder.

At the end of the day, don't abuse `static` to store state across invocations. Instead use explicit handles for the state. If you  wish to transparently *cache* data, and things get out of hand with `static`. You can consider abstracting the state of the cache with explicit initialization/access functions which are then easier to use in a thread-safe / thread-local manner. This is much easier in C++ than it is in C.